# Native Script is not showing res:// image

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm following the NativeScript tutorial, but when I'm trying to load the image with res:// is not working with iOS.

```
<Image src="res://logo" stretch ="none" />
```

The file is in the App_Resources/iOS/logo.png

UPDATE:

Now works:

1.- Uninstall the app from the device/emulator

2.- Then do a new `tns build ios` to get a fresh build

Answer (score 7):

Related steps for the same issue but with Android.

```
tns platform remove Android
tns platform add Android
tns run Android
```

Added explanation: The issue here is that your app isn't really running from AppResources. It is actually running from platform/ios and platform/android, both of which are compiled during a fresh build.

So when you add an image under AppResources, great, but unless you rebuild the app is still running on outdated resources found in platform/ios and platform/android.

Removing the platforms and adding the platforms will ensure the folders your app is using mimic App Resources. And your image will be available.

Comment: Thanks .. I solved the bug this way only.. what a waste of time though.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me.

1. Uninstall the app from the emulator
2. Re-run your build / livesync
3. Done

Answer (score 1):

I expect the issue is with your use of the nativescript cli.

To compile and run a new app, you should run `tns prepare ios`, then `tns build ios` then `tns launch ios`. Alternatively `tns run ios` completes all these steps. So bear in mind that when adding new platforms, plugins or resources, you should re-run the prepare command.

Comment: I tried with `ths prepare ios`, but if you don't uninstall the app from the emulator  the images still cached

Comment: But if you are just adding new images, that shouldn't effect it? Should only be an issue if your image changes but keeps the same file name...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the tag **stretch ="none"**. It have an space between **ch** and **=**. There is an error on Visual Code snippets. Maybe this is the case.